# How can I detect if my phone is in a "Normal calls are restricted by access control" state, blocking incoming and outgoing calls

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, system-error

Sometimes this error occurs on my cell (a Lenny 2 with *android 5.1*). I'll only notice the error when I try to make a call, there are no obvious warnings that something is erroneous i.e. signal strength is fine - perfect.
I can't receive calls then either, this can be pretty bad as you can imagine.

I tried the standard things, resting to factory defaults, only using the stock apps, updating everything, contacting phone manufacturer and network provider to no avail.

When the error occurs, its **easily** fixed by switching into airplane mode for a sec and back again.

---

**What I would like to do:**

Create a small app that periodically checks if I can do a call or can be called i.e. checking if the device is connected to the network correctly. 
And if something isnt working correctly, it automatically does the airplane-mode switch.

- Is there a method for doing such a test, without actually dialing a
  number?