# What does the message "Normal calls are restricted by access control" mean?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, calls

I'm trying to call someone on an Android phone (UK, dual SIM), but instead of ringing, I'm getting about 6 seconds of silence then a popup system message (plain text in a while box):

> **Normal calls are restricted by access control**
>
> Okay

Then the call attempt ends.

What does this mean? My phone was working fine earlier, I haven't installed anything or changed any settings, I have credit, etc etc.

---

I saw a question where [someone with the same error message was asking how to programmatically detect this state](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/159301/normal-calls-are-restricted-by-access-control-blocking-incoming-and-outgoing), but their suggested quick fix of flicking airplane mode on and off didn't immediately fix it (and doesn't help me understand what it means).

Answer (score 1):

It is not a network problem, it's a device problem.

We tested by changing the SIM. The SIM with the issue was swapped to another handset and worked fine. The SIM from the working handset swapped into the faulty one and had the exact same problem. This proves it is a device, not a network issue.

Comment: I was getting this problem on one device in areas where signal on that one network was weak. I didn't get the same problem on the same SIM on a different device in the same area, or on the same SIM and device in a different area

Answer (score 0):

It's a carrier related problem - not Android or device . See

- [MIUI forum](http://en.miui.com/thread-116409-1-1.htm)
- [Google help forum](https://support.google.com/nexus/forum/AAAANseOu187CMqg1kaQEg/?hl=en)

> This is caused by your provider. You should give them a call and explain the problem....

(and it points to Android forum discussion)

Comment: You may need to register to see MIUI thread and search for thread-116409-1-1.htm . I got it from [Google search](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Normal+calls+are+restricted+by+access+control&oq=Normal+calls+are+restricted+by+access+control&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60j0l2.1919j0j4&client=ms-android-motorola&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) which has many more references

Comment: Was your problem fixed?